Partial derivative of transfer function in Laplace domain
For some LTI transfer function $g(t,\rho)$ with a constant parameter $\rho$,
with the transformed equivalent:
$$\begin{align}
g(t,\rho)&\leftrightarrows G(s,\rho)\\
\end{align}$$
Is it equivalent to take the partial derivative with respect to $\rho$ in either domain?
IE does it hold that:
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial\rho}\big(s,\rho_k\big)\ \leftrightarrows \frac{\partial g}{\partial\rho}\big(t,\rho_k\big)$$

I think it follows from $k,f(t)\leftrightarrows k,F(s)$...

$g(t,\rho)$ is not $g(x(t),\rho)$

Yes, I think it is equivalent to take the partial derivative in either domain.
By definition we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
\lim_{\delta\rho\to 0}g(t, \rho+\delta\rho)=g(t,\rho)+\delta\rho\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial\rho}(t,\rho)\\
\lim_{\delta\rho\to 0}G(s, \rho+\delta\rho)=G(s,\rho)+\delta\rho\ \frac{\partial G}{\partial\rho}(s,\rho)
\end{cases}
$$
Consequently if $g(t,\rho)\leftrightarrows G(s,\rho)$ and $g(t,\rho+\delta\rho)\leftrightarrows G(s,\rho+\delta\rho)$ it also must hold that:
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial\rho}(t,\rho)\leftrightarrows\frac{\partial G}{\partial\rho}(s,\rho)
$$
